# What problems may be caused by redundant features?

Tags: regression, classification, feature-selection, overfitting

Regarding feature selection in machine learning (e.g., classification or regression) tasks, what would be the biggest problems if two features are somewhat redundant?

For example, we try to predict the price of a house. Let's say there are three features related to area size, among other things:

- Entire lot size
- Size of the house (inside, not including yards)
- Size of the master bedroom

First of all, would you call them redundant?  IMO they are overlapping (although not entirely redundant). Moreover, are there any other problems if we include all three features in the regression? Would it cause accuracy loss or overfitting, etc?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is called multicollinearity, where the predictors in the model are correlated. In order to know if they are "overlapping", one can check on the variance inflation factor (VIF) or other measures.

In terms of accuracy, correlation between predictors won't cause decrease of accuracy, just cause the standard error be to large for the coefficient. Of course, an over-fitting model might cause the model to be less robust.

However, according to one paper in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity)

```
"The presence of multicollinearity doesn't affect the efficacy of
extrapolating the fitted model to new data provided that the predictor
variables follow the same pattern of multicollinearity
in the new data as in the data on which the regression model is based"
```